# Prove that the semidefinite matrix always exists for any given X

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Can I prove that for any given matrix $X$, $\exists W_1, W_2$ such that

$$\begin{bmatrix} W_1 & (1/2) X \\ (1/2) X^T & W_2 \end{bmatrix} \succeq 0$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it is possible for every matrix $X$.

The reasoning is obtained from the following manipulation.

If $W_1$ is $m\times m$, $W_2$ is $n\times n$, $V_1$ is $1\times m$, $V_2$ is $1\times n$ and $X$ is $m\times n$, then, using block matrix multiplication, we get

$\begin{bmatrix} V_1 & V_2\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} W_1 & (1/2) X \\ (1/2) X^T & W_2 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} V_1^{T} \\ V_2^{T}\end{bmatrix}=V_1W_1V_1^T+\frac{1}{2}V_2X^TV_1^T+\frac{1}{2}V_1XV_2^T+V_2W_2V_2^T=V_1W_1V_1^T+\frac{1}{2}(V_1XV_2)^T+\frac{1}{2}V_1XV_2^T+V_2W_2V_2^T$

The second and the third terms are the same, as all of the terms are numbers and the transpose of a number is itself.

$\begin{bmatrix} V_1 & V_2\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} W_1 & (1/2) X \\ (1/2) X^T & W_2 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix} V_1^{T} \\ V_2^{T}\end{bmatrix}=V_1XV_2^T+V_1W_1V_1^T+V_2W_2V_2^T$

In the right hand side of the last equation, the first term is the arbitrary one and it would be a multi-variable polynomial of degree $2$. The second and the third one are also of degree 2. So, even if $X$ is chosen such that it goes to negative values, if $W_1$ and $W_2$ are chosen to be positive-definite matrices, they can be scaled to compensate the negative value of $V_1XV_2^T$.

Comment: Thank you! And I was also thinking of use SVD to achieve the similar result.

Comment: @v-2, I am glad, it was helpful

Answer (score 0):

Note that a symmetric matrix is positive semidefinite if and only if it has non-negative eigenvalues.  Note also that $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $M$ if and only if $\lambda + \alpha$ is an eigenvalue of $M + \alpha I$.

With that, it suffices to take $W_1 = W_2 = \alpha I$ for a sufficiently large $\alpha > 0$.